# Unable to input numbers in TextField

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to create a calculator to calculate the power energy and its cost.
The following is my code and although it does not have error, i can't input numbers. I cant input alphabets because i restricted it but i cant input numbers too.

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

ok_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, multiplyClick);
back_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, backClick);

var multiSym:Boolean  =  false; 
var backSym:Boolean  =  false;

usage.restrict = "0-9";
power.restrict = "0-9";
power.border = true;
usage.border = true;

var input1:String;
var input2:String;
var multiResult:Number;

function multiplyClick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    multiSym = true;
    backSym = false;

    input1 = usage.text;
    input2 = power.text;

    if(multiSym == true){
        multiResult = parseInt(input1)* parseInt(input2);
        multiResult.toString();
        total_power.text  =  String(multiResult);
    } else {
        total_power.text = "Please Choose an option";
    }   
}

function backClick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    multiSym = false;
    backSym = true;
}

stop();
```

can someone help me?
Thank you

Comment: Verify that your TextFields are input ones and that's not a font problem by embedding the used font or using a device's one (for example)...

Comment: It sounds like you are working in Flash IDE. If you are using an embedded font make sure you have embedded the numbers in the character ranges there - select your textfield and under "Character" click on "Embed ...". And make sure the font supports numbers as akmozo said - just type some numbers into your textfield in Flash and make sure they are visible